# Microservices Monitoring Using Status Code

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices

We are using Amazon ECS for micro-services based architecture. We are right now using ALB service monitoring with target-group associated with each service in an ECS cluster.

Right now, We are facing difficulty to monitor the microservices as they are hosted under route 53 private hosted zone.

We have tried to monitor Route 53 health monitoring but route 53 doesn't allow to monitor the health of the endpoints with a simple routing policy.

> Ref:
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html

We need to monitor the status code of each microservice at any interval of time.

We have also setup health-check for each microservice. Example: service-a.domain/ping. We need a status-page which represent the health of all available service we add using the status code we add. Also, any way if we can monitor them from application load balancer target group).

What will be the best way to monitor every microservice. ?

Comment: ECS itself does the job of health monitoring. If any of the microservices goes down, ecs cluster takes care of bringing up another instance of that microservice.

Comment: You can also use hystrix dashboard, sleuth and zipkin to see the health of your microservices but with aws ecs console, we didn't feel the need to have one.

Comment: Yeah. ECS Cluster takes cares of the service if its health is not good. But I need some sort of dashboard something similar to consul health check which can check the status code of the service. For example. Status page of Atlassian.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate Axibase Time Series Database with AWS Route53 health checks via CloudWatch to create a consolidated view of the microservices as described [here](https://axibase.com/use-cases/integrations/aws/route53-health-checks/#availability-portal).

Container-based microservices tend to have short lifespans, so we recommend to reduce AWS CloudWatch job frequency to 5 minutes compared to the default 15 minutes. Similarly, given that Health Checks are likely to be created and removed on short notice, it's better to copy their attributes to the database every 5 minutes.

[image: ATSD Route 53 portal]

Disclaimer: I work for Axibase.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

https://github.com/brotandgames/ciao

It's open source self-hosted. So, you can host it internally and thus it will be able to access private microservices and do status check. It provides nice mail and webhooks flexible notifications.